# SAS - Reformatting from continuous variable to categorical

Tags: sas

I've been googling for a couple of hours (on and off) to find an answer to this question.

I have a numerical (categorical) field that I think SAS is automatically assuming to be continuous.  It's a customer number and SAS is automatically binning it in graphs when I need to it as an individual element.  Can someone with some SAS experience please explain to me how to reformat a continuous number to a categorical?

There's not really any point me posting any code because it's a very generic question. My data looks like this and it's the custno field that I'm trying to change to categorical using the format function.

```
Obs custno gender age postcode Region cnt 
1 1 Male 48 18 S 50 
2 2 Female 56 20 N 38 
3 3 Female 51 25 N 50 
4 4 Male 27 9 W 16
```

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks,
beef

```
data customers_full;
merge customers_pc (in=cust_pc) orders_flat (in=ord);
by custno;
if cust_pc;
drop date _FREQ_ _TYPE_;
format gender gender_fmt.;
custno_char = put(custno, best32. -1);
/*Region = tranwrd(Region,"N","North"); */
/*if Region="N" then Region="North";*/
run;
```

Comment: Although I posted an answer, I'd be curious to see how this happens as I can't see it at first glance.

Comment: i've just had a shot at using that - entered the code into my original post.  getting a syntax error (it might be something obvious, i've only just picked up sas...) thx @Reeza

Comment: In PUT, the last parameter is L (letter L) not a 1. This is used to left align the output. And now that I think about it, it should be -r, for right alignment. It's also optional.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a character variable rather than a numeric variable, you'll need to create a new variable to do this.

```
custno_char = put(custno, best32. -l);
```

Then use this variable in your programs instead.

EDIT: 
-l is used to left align the data, if you want it right aligned change it to -r. 
You can also omit it entirely, since it's an optional parameter.

```
custno_char = put(custno, best32. -r);
```